# Discord.js multi role check

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

so ive been trying to find a better way to check multiple roles for commands on my discord bot so far the best i can do is }else{

```
run(message) {
    if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Pheonix")){

        return message.say('These are dark times. . .', {files: ["./resources/videos/darktimes.mp4"]});
    }else{
        if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Renowned Wizard")){
        return message.say('These are dark times. . .', {files: ["./resources/videos/darktimes.mp4"]});
    }else{

  return message.say('*Patreon restricted.*');
```

And i was wondering is there some way i could chuck this in an array and use whatever is in the array as a checker for roles is there any ways to go about this?
okay so i tried to add onto with an array but i cant get that to function

```
    var morsmordreRoles = [
        'Dev',
        'Renowned Wizard',
        'Pheonix',
        'Moderator'
    ]
    if(message.member.roles.find("name", morsemordreRoles)){

    return message.say('*You mark the sky with the presence of The Dark Lord* ', {files: ["./resources/gifs/morsmordre.gif"] });
}else{
    return message.say('*Death Eater restricted.*');
}



}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an array, you can use a foreach and a bool check to check if the user has **any** of the roles in the array, also you should use `.cache.some` instead of `find` in discord.js v12 as seen [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-check-if-a-guild-member-has-a-certain-role)

Example:

```
var morsmordreRoles = [
        'Dev',
        'Renowned Wizard',
        'Pheonix',
        'Moderator'
    ]
    var hasRole = false;
    morsmordreRoles.forEach(findrole =>{
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === findrole)) hasRole = true; //if user has role, sets bool to true
    })

    if(hasRole === true){
        //code when has role
    }
    else{
        //code when has no role
    }
```

Comment: It is throwing a type error of undefined one 'some'

Comment: hmm might be the async

Comment: it might be because you're using discord.js v11, check your package.json and if you are using v11, try to switch to v12 because v11 might be discontinued soon. If you need help with switching to v12, try [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

Comment: i updated and this is making alot more sense now ty