# Discord bot guildMember.roles.cache.has(roleID1 || roleID2)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am writing a bot to verify roles on a discord server and I came across one snag when I write more than one variable to `guildMember.roles.cache.has()`. The bot does not check all of them, it is possible to do something for bot to check multiple roles with operators? Thank you

```
if (command === 'verify' && mcname !=null && message.channel.type == "dm") {                                                                  
  //IF COMMAND IS VERIFY,MCNAME NOT EMPTY AND CHANNEL IS DM
  const guild = await message.client.guilds.fetch(serverid);
  const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);

  if (guildMember.roles.cache.has(roleID1 || roleID2 || roleID3 || roleID4 || roleID5 || roleID6 || roleID7)) {
```

I have defined role ids upper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422854/discord-js-multi-role-check) may help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store those role IDs in an array and check if the member has any of these. `guildMember.roles.cache` returns a collection of roles so you can use the [`some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method to check if any of the member's role's ID is included in the array of IDs:

```js
const roleIDs = [roleID1, roleID2, roleID3, roleID4, roleID5, roleID6, roleID7];

if (guildMember.roles.cache.some(role => roleIDs.includes(role.id))) {
// ...
```

Try the snippet below:

```js
const guildMember = {
  roles: {
    cache: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '5' }, { id: '9' }]
  }
}

const roleIDs1 = ['2', '3', '4']
const roleIDs2 = ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

console.log('Member has a role ID included in roleIDs1?', guildMember.roles.cache.some(role => roleIDs1.includes(role.id)))
console.log('Member has a role ID included in roleIDs2?', guildMember.roles.cache.some(role => roleIDs2.includes(role.id)))
```